# how to add fixed container above x number of scrollable card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a fixed `buildHelpCard(context, alldata)` above the scrollable list but whenever I try to add the `buildHelpCard` the list got disappeared and only the `buildHelpCard` is showing ... can you guys please suggest me how to fix this issues

---

**here is my code**

````
```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../colors/constants.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class duesDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  var data;
  var count;
  duesDetails(this.data, this.count);

  @override
  _duesDetailsState createState() => _duesDetailsState();
}

class _duesDetailsState extends State<duesDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var alldata = widget.data; // added all value to data for easy access
    int count = widget.count;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(alldata),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.03),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 22, bottom: 22, left: 16, right: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Text(
                                '${alldata[count]['pay list'][index]['discription']}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Capital',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 50,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/facebook.png'),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: alldata[count]['pay count'] == null ? 0 : alldata[count]['pay count'],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }


AppBar buildAppBar(var data) {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(.05),
    elevation: 0,
    //title: Obx(() => Text('Randas ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
    title: Text("${data[0]['name']} Pay Details", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
   iconTheme: IconThemeData(
     color: kPrimaryColor,
     size: 28.0,
   ),
  );
}

  Container buildHelpCard(BuildContext context, var data) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              // left side padding is 40% of total width
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
              top: 20,
              right: 20,
            ),
            height: 130,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF60BE93),
                  Color(0xFF1B8D59),
                ],
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "${data[5]["title"]}\n",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .headline6
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "${data[5]["dis"]}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 210.0, 20.0),
            child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/friends.svg"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

```
````

NOTE - I want to add buildHelpCard(context, alldata) function above the start of the card list... but when I try to do this the list got disappeared

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  child: Column(
        children: [

     buildHelpCard()
      Expanded(child:
              ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 22, bottom: 22, left: 16, right: 16),
                child:........
```